# Saving to a new file each time

Tags: matlab

previously i wrote a code for execution of LBP. The problem i face is that i need to the data from the histogram a different file each time and not the same file each time. How do i do it? Need some guidance over it. The code is below is the one i have written for LBP.

```
%% LBP
scale = 2.^[7 6 5; 0 -inf 4; 1 2 3]; 
for i=2:6:m-1
    for j=2:6:n-1
        for k=i:i+6
           for l=j:j+6
             J0=I2(i,j);
             I3(i-1,j-1)=I2(i-1,j-1)>J0;
             I3(i-1,j)=I2(i-1,j)>J0;
             I3(i-1,j+1)=I2(i-1,j+1)>J0; 
             I3(i,j+1)=I2(i,j+1)>J0;
             I3(i+1,j+1)=I2(i+1,j+1)>J0; 
             I3(i+1,j)=I2(i+1,j)>J0; 
             I3(i+1,j-1)=I2(i+1,j-1)>J0; 
             I3(i,j-1)=I2(i,j-1)>J0;
             LBP(i,j)=I3(i-1,j-1)*2^7+I3(i-1,j)*2^6+I3(i-1,j+1)*2^5+I3(i,j+1)*2^4+I3(i+1,j+1)*2^3+I3(i+1,j)*2^2+I3(i+1,j-1)*2^1+I3(i,j-1)*2^0;
           end
        end
        LBP=uint8(LBP);
        LBPv=reshape(LBP,1,size(LBP,1)*size(LBP,2));
        Hist=hist(LBPv,0:255);
        save('C:\Users\Lakshmen\Documents\MATLAB\HistInf','Hist');
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a counter variable which you increment each time you call the SAVE function. You would use this counter to generate filenames by appending it.

```
BASE_DIR = 'C:\Users\Lakshmen\Documents\MATLAB';

counter = 1;
for i=..
    for j=...
        Hist = hist(..);

        fname = sprintf('HistInf%03d.mat', counter);
        save(fullfile(BASE_DIR,fname), 'Hist');
        counter = counter + 1;
    end
end
```

Otherwise, you can just use a cellarray to save the values at each iteration, then save this variable into a single MAT-file at the end.

Comment: 2) how to save it to cell array? is it for example Hist1(counter,1)= Hist? i am just trying.. if wrong correct me....

Comment: @cnnlakshmen: 1) correct, SPRINTF returns the result as a string 2) cell-arrays are accessed with curly braces: `Hist1{counter} = hist(..);`

Comment: If i want to save it to a matrix, then i shld type Hist1[counter] = hist(..); Am i right?

Comment: @cnnlakshmen: HIST returns a row vector: `Hist1(counter,:) = hist(..);`. I suggest you take some time and read throught the user guide in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to produce unique identifiers is the following :

```
fname=sprintf('myalgo%i.mat',sum(floor(1000*clock))
```

Thus the ID of the file changes every millisecond ...

Best 
AL

Comment: if the goal is to generate random file names (rather than a sequence as in file01, file02, etc..), you should use the [TEMPNAME](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/tempname.html) function: `[~,fname]=fileparts(tempname)`